# Display specific month on datepicker without changing selected date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

i'm using two datepickers to select range of dates, and I have the following problem:

When i select "start date" on **datepicker I**, I update *minDate* on the second one (analogously when selecting "end date" I update *maxDate* on the first one).

The problem is, that updating *maxDate* or *minDate* causes refreshing of datepicker.

So, for example if someone was browsing months on **datepicker II** and then selects some date on **datepicker I** then **datepicker II** will refresh and display goes back to last selected date on **datepicker II**, instead of staying at month user was browsing.

I already know the way to find out which month was last displayed on datepicker - by using "onChangeMonthYear" option.

The question is how to force datepicker to navigate to month I want (without actually changing selected date).

I'd really appreciate any help or suggestions.

Code, as requested. I'm using AngularJS, but I guess you can easily see how this would be translated into JQuery:

```
scope.fromDate.onChangeMonthYear = function(year, month){
    //saving info about date I
};

scope.toDate.onChangeMonthYear = function(year, month){
    //saving info about date II
};

scope.fromDate.onSelect = function(selectedDate) {
    element.find(".date-to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
};

scope.toDate.onSelect = function(selectedDate) {
    element.find(".date-from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

according to jquery ui datepicker api reference:

```
// getter
var minDate = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate" );

// setter
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1) );
```

this should be used after the initialization, without reseting the datepicker

Comment: I have no problems with setting "minDate". I want to somehow change displayed month on the other datepicker, or prevent it from refreshing.

Comment: the datepicker only refresh if you call the datepicker constructor again. Also, if you are using the same css class on both datepickers to execute the plugin, you will have problems